# Git: quit "typing" mode

Tags: git, console

I accidentaly typed `git commit -m "name:` and after that every new line in console starts with ">" symbol and git doesn't react to commands. `q`, `:q`, `:q!` don't help.

Please, tell me how to quit this satanic mode.

[image]

Comment: This could be because of not closed double quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a satanic mode, you are just inputting a multiline commit message. The `>` shows you that your multi-line string continues. `:q` and similar are `vim` commands, but you are not inside `vim`.

So if you type

```
$ git commit -m "foo
> bar"
```

you will end up with a commit message

```
foo
bar
```

If you want to end the multi-line comment just type the closing quote `"` and press enter, then the multi-line message is sent.

If you want to abort and type the command again with a one-line message, just type <kbd>CTRL + C</kbd> for `cancel` and reissue your command.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this will work:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

CTRL+C also will stop a process which is running in the Git bash.  For example, if you were grepping for some files and you decided you wanted to stop early, you could use CTRL+C to stop it.